# Corollary (?) of projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, projective-geometry

In a course on field invariants (in particular the diophantine dimension) the following claim is made.

> For an algebraically closed field $K$, every system of $k$ forms in $n > k$ variables has a non-zero solution by the projective Nullstellensatz. Hence, the diophantine dimension of $K$ is $0$.

I can see why the diophantine dimension follows from the first claim, but after digging up my notes on algebraic geometry, I found this formulation of the projective Nullstellensatz (a bit altered to avoid introducting unneeded notation):

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. A system of forms in $n$ variables over $K$ has *no* nonzero solution if and only if there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the ideal $I$ generated by the forms contains all forms of degree at least $N$.

How does this theorem (which does not mention the number of forms in the system!) imply the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sketch of the solution a colleague of mine eventually found:

Suppose the ideal $I$ is generated by forms $Q_1, \ldots, Q_k$. We know that $\sqrt{I} \subseteq (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ where $\sqrt{I}$ denotes the radical of $I$. If we can show that the inclusion is strict, then by the homogeneous Nullstellensatz we would have that $I$ is isotropic.

Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $\sqrt{I} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Then $\sqrt{I}$ is a minimal prime ideal containing $I$, but by Krull's *Höhensatz* we must have that $\sqrt{I}$ cannot have height $> k$.

Answer (score 1):

When we say all of forms of degree $N$, it includes $x_1^N,x_2^N,\ldots, x_n^N$. The only common zero for them is $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ which is not part of the projective space and defines empty set as the zero locus.

Now if the number of equations $k$ is less than the the number of variables, $n$,  each of them can cut down the dimension by $1$, ending up with a variety of dimension $n-k$ or more which would be an infinite set.

Comment: This dimension argument does not work in the affine case, where a system of two equations in three unknowns can have no solution. Can you make it more formal why this works in the projective case?

Comment: @Bib-lost: Because the dimension statement *is* valid in the affine case, provided the intersection is non-empty.    Now for homogeneous equations, there is always a non-empty intersection, because the origin is contained in the intersection!  After observing this, we can pass to the projective context by deleting the origin and quotienting out by scaling.  (But we crucially used the origin to get the non-empty intersection in the first place!)  I think this is discussed near the end of Hartshorne, Ch. I .

Comment: I will try to look up this reference, if it is freely accessible. I had hoped for a more elementary argument though.